# JMeter Summary Report questions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

1) Can I say there is a defect when the error % is 70%?

2) How do I know if is a defect in API response.

3) What is throughput?

4) How do I explain the summary report to the developer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Value of `70` in `Error %` means that 70% of samplers with that label have failed. If you don't have any assertions most probably there is H[TTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) >= 400 for this particular request(s)
2. If you expect [status code 200 OK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) and response has different status equal or above 400 - JMeter automatically marks the request as failed and stores response message in .jtl results file. You can also save response body just in case your API returns some meaningful error message, to do this add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
   ```
3. `Throughput` is number of requests per unit of time. For example if you run 100 requests in 60 seconds the throughput will be 1.6 requests per second, if you run 200 request in 100 seconds the throughput will be 3.3 requests per second, etc. See [load testing glossary](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420385-Glossary) for comprehensive explanation of this and other terms.
4. Summary report doesn't tell the full story, it can be used as a basis for regression testing or as a quick overview. You should consider generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) - this way you will be able to correlate increasing number of threads (virtual users) with response times, throughput, error rate, etc. It also makes sense to monitor the application under test resources usage with i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which allows you to check whether your application has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network and Disk usage.